# Display all comments post not work in Edit comment page

Tags: php

I am trying to show all comments related to the post the comment being edited belongs to.

My code (based on [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_comment_meta_box/))

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'all_display_comments_add_meta_box' );

function all_display_comments_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'commentsdiv', __( 'Comments' ), 'my_post_comment_meta_box', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function my_post_comment_meta_box( $post ) {

    $total         = get_comments(
        array(
            'post_id' => $post->ID,
            'number'  => 1,
            'count'   => true,
        )
    );
    $wp_list_table = _get_list_table( 'WP_Post_Comments_List_Table' );
    $wp_list_table->display( true );

    if ( 1 > $total ) {
        echo '<p id="no-comments">' . __( 'No comments yet.' ) . '</p>';
    } else {
        $hidden = get_hidden_meta_boxes( get_current_screen() );
        if ( ! in_array( 'commentsdiv', $hidden, true ) ) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){commentsBox.get(<?php echo $total; ?>, 10);});</script>
            <?php
        }

        ?>
        <p class="hide-if-no-js" id="show-comments"><a href="#commentstatusdiv" onclick="commentsBox.load(<?php echo $total; ?>);return false;"><?php _e( 'Show comments' ); ?></a> <span class="spinner"></span></p>
        <?php
    }

    wp_comment_trashnotice();
}
```

[image]
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do these, in order to make the "Show comments" part works properly:

1. On the "Edit Comment" page (at `wp-admin/comment.php`), the first parameter passed to the meta box callback (your `my_post_comment_meta_box()` function) is a [`WP_Comment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment/) object and not a `WP_Post` object, so you need to manually define `$post` in your function.
2. Add back the `get-comments` *nonce* to your function, just like in the original [`post_comment_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_comment_meta_box/) function.
3. After that, echo a hidden input with `post_ID` as the input `id` and the comment's post ID as the value.
4. The meta box uses a global JavaScript variable/object named `commentsBox` that's defined in `wp-admin/js/post.js`, so you need to load that script on the page.

So your function should begin like this:

```php
function my_post_comment_meta_box( $comment ) { // use $comment and not $post
    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID ); // manually define $post

    // Add the post ID input.
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="post_ID" value="' . $post->ID . '">';

    // Then the AJAX nonce.
    wp_nonce_field( 'get-comments', 'add_comment_nonce', false );
```

And then you can use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) to load the `post.js` script:

```php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the script only if the current page is comment.php
    if ( 'comment' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'post' );
    }
}
```

### Update

If you want the comment's action links such as "Reply" and "Quick Edit" to work, then:

1. In the above `my_admin_enqueue_scripts()` function, add the following after the `wp_enqueue_script( 'post' );` :

   ```php
   // Enqueue the comment reply script.
   wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-comments' );
   ```
2. Then after that *function*, add this which outputs the inline comment reply form: (We have to put it in the header so that the `action` input is not overwritten. There's a jQuery/JS way to overcome the issue, but I'd just use the following, and don't worry, the form is hidden by default.)

   ```php
   add_action( 'in_admin_header', 'my_in_admin_header' );
   function my_in_admin_header() {
       if ( 'comment' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
           wp_comment_reply( '-1' );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Many thanks! Works perfect :-)

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) And I have just added an update to my answer, so check/try it out.

Comment: Thanks. This functionality also works :-)

Comment: No, there was a problem after adding the last change. If you try to save the comment, then the budent will write "Unknown action".

Comment: Video Problem https://youtu.be/shhlbpu76Zo

Comment: Undo your changes (remove the `wp_comment_reply()` and `ajax-response` div from the `my_post_comment_meta_box()` function) and then follow the steps in the revised "Update" section.

Comment: Thanks! This it works.
And the last question - what needs to be changed so that comments are loaded not in 10 pieces, but all comments once. If there are a lot of them, then many times necessary to push link  to "show more comments".

Comment: I'm glad it worked, and sorry for the late reply, but you should post another question regarding limiting the number of comments, if you haven't already found a solution :)

Comment: Hi. New question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/396736/how-to-one-click-view-all-comments-on-post-wordpress-admin